# How to use ansible without ssh keys - getpwnam() MODULE FAILURE

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use ansible without setting ssh keys. I want to log in with username and password. I have installed on the master `sshpass`.

My **directory** layout looks like this:

```
ansible.cfg
inventory/
    hosts
    group_vars/
        all.yaml
roles
   whoami/
       tasks/
            main.yaml
site.yaml
```

**ansible.cfg:**

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = false
inventory = inventory
```

**inventory/hosts:**

```
[defaults]
machine
```

**inventory/group_vars/all.yaml:**

```
---
# file: group_vars/all
ansible_user: username
ansible_password: password
```

**main.yaml:**

```
---

- name: whoami
  shell: whoami
```

**site.yaml:**

```
---
- hosts: machine
    roles:
        - whoami
```

if i **run**:

```
$ansible machine -i inventory/ -m shell -a "whoami"
```

it is executed **successfully**:

```
machine | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
username
```

whereas if I **run**:

```
$ansible-playbook -i inventory site.yml -v
```

I get this:

```
fatal: [machine]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false, 
"failed": true, 
"invocation": {
    "module_name": "setup"
}, 
"module_stderr": "OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u1, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 2908\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 0\r\nShared connection to machine closed.\r\n", 
"module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_QAFcSD/ansible_module_setup.py\", line 134, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_QAFcSD/ansible_module_setup.py\", line 126, in main\r\n    data = get_all_facts(module)\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_QAFcSD/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/facts.py\", line 3518, in get_all_facts\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_QAFcSD/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/facts.py\", line 3457, in ansible_facts\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_QAFcSD/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/facts.py\", line 171, in __init__\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_QAFcSD/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/facts.py\", line 513, in get_user_facts\r\nKeyError: 'getpwnam(): name not found: username'\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/username/playbook/my_ansible/site.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
machine                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: How about using current Ansible release? `ansible-playbook` fails on gathering facts which `ansible` does not perform. There were issues in the past, just [search GitHub](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17029). The whole fact-gathering part has been rewritten since. I don't see a point in dealing with old versions.

Comment: I was running version 2.2.1.0 which seems to be affected by this bug. I upgrade to version 2. will update to 2.4.1.0 and it works smoothly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running version 2.2.1.0 which is affected by this bug [GitHub](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17029). I upgraded to version 2. 4.1.0 with:

```
$pip install ansible
```

and it works smoothly.

Thanks to [techraf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2947502/techraf)